# Changes required to run Kubernetes provisioning script (Kubernetes + CoreOS in Microsoft Azure) to run in production environment?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, coreos, weave

I am planning to deploy a production deployment with 'Kubernetes + CoreOS' in Microsoft. And planning to run couple of micro services in the cluster. My plan is to have 5 nodes, I will have 5/6 pods to run each will have 3-5 instances. I was following the official documentation of Kubernetes, I found https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/README.md is really helpful, the script works awesome. But I don't think that its production ready for my use case , as

- the deployed VMs are not assigned to Availability Sets
- Not able to specify an existing Virtual Network, Resources, location etc.

I am a newbie in this field. Can someone help me out to let me know what all steps to be taken to make this a real production environment ?

Answer (score 1):

> the deployed VMs are not assigned to Availability Sets

It is true indeed, as an author and maintainer of the guide, I will welcome a pull-request to enable this, which should be quite easy and probably similar how [affinity groups are currently handled](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/7d936fe4cabac9365e5ff4abf6e48e93bf124efa/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/lib/azure_wrapper.js#L144).

> Not able to specify an existing Virtual Network, Resources, location etc.

This is a very good point, however it's probably best to refactor current ad-hoc JavaScript wrapping to something more streamlined with [Azure Resource Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/), which hasn't been generally available at the time I implemented that integration.